# Makefile error at 36% trying to install OpenCV 4 on RaspBerry Pi 4

Tags: opencv, pi-4, make

I've been trying to install OpenCV on my RaspBerry Pi 4 using:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$cwd/installation/OpenCV-"$cvVersion" \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D WITH_TBB=ON \
            -D WITH_V4L=ON \
            -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=$cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
        -D WITH_QT=ON \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

This completes successfully but when I then run `make -j$(nproc)` I am getting the error `**make: [Makefile:163: all] Error 2**` Here are the last few lines of install before the error.

```
[ 36%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/view/singlefilterview.cpp.o

[ 36%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/src/view/translationsmatchview.cpp.o

[ 36%] Building CXX object modules/cvv/CMakeFiles/opencv_cvv.dir/opencv_cvv_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o

[ 36%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cvv.so

[ 36%] Built target opencv_cvv

make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

What is going wrong? I've been following this guide exactly so I'm not sure what's wrong. https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/ Thank you!

Comment: What operating system do you use? Why isn't it an option to you use **opencv** from the default software repository if you use Raspbian?

Comment: I had a similar problem on a RPi 3 and I had to lower the number of threads (-jX) and everything went well. Maybe it can be useful to you.

Comment: @Ephemeral I wish that worked. I changed make to make -j1 and it still errored out at 48%. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @greyBow, and without `-j` maybe ? just `make` ? (I know that for my case the compilation took a very long time) I think It' s a 'thread' synchronization problem , then without `-j` we force thread sync. I seem to have thought like this during the same problem

Comment: Try following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884682/error-in-building-opencv-with-ffmpeg
Worked for me

Comment: Try following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884682/error-in-building-opencv-with-ffmpeg
Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://gist.github.com/willprice/abe456f5f74aa95d7e0bb81d5a710b60), Willprice user say exaclty what I say in the comment :

> OpenCV builds can sometimes fail due to using too many threads, try
>   running make instead of make -j $(nproc)

or

> Make sure to increase your swap file size!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to install using pip and python3 with the command `sudo apt install python3-opencv`. It works for me every time and it installs the latest version of opencv

Answer (score 1):

I would try installing with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv #For python3
sudo apt-get install python-opencv #For python2
```

and if that doesn't work, compile it from source with [this script](https://gist.github.com/willprice/abe456f5f74aa95d7e0bb81d5a710b60)

Read the comments from the gists, they solve some problems that you might encounter.